# Showing Google routes as a layer in ArcGIS Pro/Online

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, google-maps, routing

So, I'm aware of the ability to use network analysis for routing in ArcGIS Pro and would like to use it. however, I'm under the constraint that we don't have licenses for Network Analyst, and we also don't have good road network data, and we are under security constraints and unable to use OpenStreetMaps. Therefore I have developed a python code to pass a series of route stops off to google maps to give me routing directions:

```
import arcpy
import csv

#input csv
csv_file_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# Import the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(open(csv_file_path, 'r'))

# Iterate over the rows of the CSV file
for i in range(len(df)):
    # Concat the POINT_X and POINT_Y columns, with a comma between them
    df.loc[i, "POINT_ALL"] = str(df.loc[i, "POINT_Y"]) + "," + str(df.loc[i, "POINT_X"])

# Concatenate all of the coordinates in a single string with forward slashes between the coordinates
coordinates = "/".join(df["POINT_ALL"])

# Add the concatenated coordinates to a URL
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + coordinates

import webbrowser

def open_link(link):
    webbrowser.open(link)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_link(url)
```

This pulls from a routing optimizer and outputs the stops to google maps as a trip, which is great for the person using the trip, but hard for the trip scheduler to visualize. I can't find if there is some way to then visualize the trip in ArcMaps again? Even as a kml or image format, it would be nice to see this in Pro or in a dashboard.

Comment: You need to decode the route (the blue line you see on google maps) into a line of points then save that out as a polyline in a Feature Class in WGS84. You need to understand whats in the  JSON dictionary that the API returns. Thats on the help page and simple search on google for the decode script, its out there on the internet.

Comment: Thank you. I have never done API programming in the past, so knowing such is an option is nice.